# using IObservable with unity

Tags: unity-container, system.reactive

I want to use the iobservable pattern to expose a stream of events.  The problem is that I'm using unity to create both the observer and the event generator.  I would rather not have to new up both of these at application start just so I can start listening for events.  Does any one have any suggestions about this?

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail? I'm not sure there's enough information here to offer advice.

Comment: The basic problem is when to start listening.  If you have two singletons in the Unity container (using container controlled lifetime manager).  They will be created as soon as they are first used, but you dont want to create them when you create the container.  So when I create the event publisher (or send the first event), its at that point in time I want the listener to be created (so that it can start listening).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. If you prefix your comment with @person's name they will be notified when the login to SO :)

Answer (score 2):

After reading your reply to my comment (sorry about the delay, see my comment) I can think of two ways of solving it.

Firstly, have the subscriber subscriber to an `IObservable` that wraps (ie. subscribes to) the yet-to-be-created `IObservable` source. This way, the subscriber can subscribe immediately, but the values won't start coming through until the source has been created.

The other choice is to create an `IObservable` flavoured version of the `EventAggregator` that ships with [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) (2.2, I haven't checked out 4). The `EventAggregator` acts as a broadcast event system, whereby any piece of code can ask for an `Event` which can be either subscribed to or published to. In your case, the event would implement `ISubject` (that is, both `IObservable` and `IObserver`).